# View section does not load on click on navigation links but when URL change manually on the browser then page load working according to url

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react js. So it is a hard problem for me to solve it.
View section does not load on click on navigation links but when URL change manually on the browser then page load working according to url

```
import AboutUs from './AboutUs';
import News from './News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

 <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={News} />
     <Route exact path="/about-us"  component={AboutUs} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

I have done lots of the way using the different code using the withRouter function but I can not able to solve this issue.

Please help me.

Comment: does your URL gets updated when you click on navigation link ? and any code of component that has the navigation link will be helpful. Also is there any error in console ?

Comment: I have fixed my issue. And the issue was in the News and AboutUs components where we have defined the Router inside the router so in the total two-time same router was called in the system. So I have just removed the router related codes from the News and AboutUs component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue. And the issue was in the News and AboutUs components where we have defined the Router inside the router so in the total two-time same router was called in the system. So I have just removed the router related codes from the News and AboutUs component.

> You can not define the multiple routers for the same pages with
>   multiple times.